# Making a Scatter Plot from a DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a DataFrame and need to make a scatter-plot from it.

I need to use 2 columns as the x-axis and y-axis and only need to plot 2 rows from the entire dataset. Any suggestions?

For example, my dataframe is below (50 states x 4 columns). I need to plot 'rgdp_change' on the x-axis vs 'diff_unemp' on the y-axis, and only need to plot for the states, "Michigan" and "Wisconsin".

[image: dataframe]

Comment: This is a pretty general question. Can you provide some code or a description - seeing your df would be helpful. If I understand you correctly, you want a scatterplot, but of only two rows. So your scatterplot will only have two points? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Of course! I'll update my post.

Comment: For future reference - [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Answer (score 1):

So from the dataframe, you'll need to select the rows from a list of the states you want: `['Michigan', 'Wisconsin']`

I also figured you would probably want a legend or some way to differentiate one point from the other. To do this, we create a colormap assigning a different color to each state. This way the code is generalizable for more than those two states.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

# generate a random df with the relevant rows, columns to your actual df
df = pd.DataFrame({'State':['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Michigan', 'Wisconsin'], 'real_gdp':[1.75*10**5, 4.81*10**4, 2.59*10**5, 1.04*10**5],
'rgdp_change': [-0.4, 0.5, 0.4, -0.5], 'diff_unemp': [-1.3, 0.4, 0.5, -11]})

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
states = ['Michigan', 'Wisconsin']
colormap = cm.viridis
colorlist = [colors.rgb2hex(colormap(i)) for i in np.linspace(0, 0.9, len(states))]

for i,c in enumerate(colorlist):
    x = df.loc[df["State"].isin(['Michigan', 'Wisconsin'])].rgdp_change.values[i]
    y = df.loc[df["State"].isin(['Michigan', 'Wisconsin'])].diff_unemp.values[i]
    legend_label = states[i]

    ax.scatter(x, y, label=legend_label, s=50, linewidth=0.1, c=c)

ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Needs axis names:  'rgdp_change' (x-axis), 'diff_unemp' (y-axis)

Answer (score 0):

Use the dataframe [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) method, but first filter the sates you need using index [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) method:

```
states =  ["Michigan", "Wisconsin"]
df[df.index.isin(states)].plot(kind='scatter', x='rgdp_change', y='diff_unemp')
```